# Including current date in file name

Tags: powershell

How do I include the date after base name of the file? 
When the PowerShell script below is executed, it will download the csv to the destination folder from the website:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://files.docparser.com/d/jvmnvggcccfxz","C:\test\IV_1.csv")
```

The output file name is `IV_1.csv`.

How do I add the date to the filename? For example filename, `IV_1-04-04-2020.csv`.

Comment: as an aside ... try to NOT use the backwards EU format or the inside out US format. instead, use the logical, sortable `yyyy-MM-dd` format. the sorting glitches are "interesting" and well worth avoiding. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

You could get the current date string with `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` from [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7), extract the filename and extension with [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.8) and [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.8), then format all the parts together with the [-f Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

```
$file = "IV_1.csv"

$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)

$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)

"{0}-{1}{2}" -f $filename, $dateString, $extension
```

**Output:**

```
IV_1-05-04-2020.csv
```

However, if your dealing with full paths, then `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` will not preserve the whole path, only the filename. You could use [`System.String.Substring()`](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html) and [`System.String.LastIndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.8) to extract the full path without the extension. This will take everything before the last `.` character.

```
$file = "C:\test\IV_1.csv"

$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

$path =  $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.'))

$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)

"{0}-{1}{2}" -f $path, $dateString, $extension
```

**Output:**

```
C:\test\IV_1-05-04-2020.csv
```

We could also wrap the above into a function:

```
function Format-FilePathWithDate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$FilePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$DateFormat
    )

    $dateString = (Get-Date).ToString($DateFormat)

    $path =  $FilePath.Substring(0, $FilePath.LastIndexOf('.'))

    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FilePath)

    "{0}-{1}{2}" -f $path, $dateString, $extension
}
```

Then use this function specifically in your scenario:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient

$file = Format-FilePathWithDate -FilePath "C:\test\IV_1.csv" -DateFormat "dd-MM-yyyy"

$client.DownloadFile("https://files.docparser.com/d/jvmnvggcccfxz", $file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert the date like this:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://files.docparser.com/d/jvmnvggcccfxz","C:\test\IV_1-$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyy')).csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep it clear and simple, but not all inline, I would do the following:

```
$dteshort = (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$file = "C:\test\IV_1-" + $dteshort + ".csv"
```

Result:

```
PS C:\>$file
C:\test\IV_1-2021-10-22.csv
```

and then just use $file in place of the second parameter:

Original line:

```
$client.DownloadFile("https://files.docparser.com/d/jvmnvggcccfxz","C:\test\IV_1.csv")
```

New line:

```
$client.DownloadFile("https://files.docparser.com/d/jvmnvggcccfxz",$file)
```